# How to Iterate over DataFrame Column and Update Column Values

Tags: python, pandas, loops, iteration

I'm trying to iterate though the abc column and update its' value, but I keep getting errors. Any help would be appreciated.

```
somedata.csv:
                    ABC
0               0.00094
1               0.00094
2               0.00094
3               0.00094
...
4999            0.00094


data = pd.read_csv("somedata.csv")
abc = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ABC'])

for column in abc:
    value = (abc - min(abc)) / (max(abc) - min(abc))
    abc = value
```

Error: numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype(' dtype('
line 72, in  
    value = (abc - min(abc)) / (max(abc) - min(abc))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there's a few things wrong. On "abc" instantiation, finish the ")". 
The line `value = (abc - min(abc)) / (max(abc) - min(abc))` is very confusing. abc you have as a dataframe column, so I assume you would like to update every row value of this column titled 'ABC'.

To get value = (ThisRowValue - min(abc)) / (max(abc) - min(abc)), utilize [Panda's max and min](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html)

I would write this

```
#Separate out the column (assuming multiple columns)
abc = df['ABC']
abc = list(map(float, abc)) #Edited to turn it into float values

list2 = [] # Empty list for storage
for this_row_value in abc: #Iterate for each value in column 'ABC'
    value = (this_row_value - abc.min()) / (abc.max() - abc.min()) #Utilize Panda's Min/Max
    list2.append(value)

#Set updated values to the column values. You can also use Pandas Update.
df['ABC'] = list2
```

Where `df` is just the dataframe object.

Comment: Thanks, but I still got the same error: numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')

Which is weird that there's an error with numpy involved.

Comment: So what's probably happening then is it's receiving in your data as strings. I assume they're numbers, probably with decimals. Convert them to floats. You can write a quick method that turns df['ABC'].tolist() , parse each one, and return the list. Then set the new Float list to the column that was ['ABC'] in the same way as above code.

Comment: float_list = list(map(float, string_list))
This will convert a list of strings to floats in one line. It also would help if you could show the data, or a snippet, from somedata.csv
I modified the above code to include this.

Comment: Still a no go. Error I got was:  abc = list(map(float, abc))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' abc_final_avg'

Don't know if you still want to help, but I added a snippet of the csv data

Comment: For future viewers @Pete way did work, I just needed to flatten the df first as included the column header (ABC) when trying to calculate the max - min